# AudioUnit/AudioUnit.h file not found

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Hi Iam using AudioToolbox Frame work in ipad App and i have added all required frameworks. App is running successfully in Ipad Simulator. But when i want run in device its showing error that AudioUnit/AudioUnit.h file not found.

Thanks

Comment: i also have this same issue

Answer (score 0):

seeing similar issues, add CoreAudio.framework